# Get SVG size from QSvgRenderer

Tags: qt, qt5, qtsvg

Suppose I have an SVG something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 100 200"
   height="600mm"
   width="300mm">
...
```

Using `QSvgRenderer::viewBoxF()` I can obtain the `0 0 100 200` viewbox, but is there any way to obtain the `width="300mm"` and `height="600mm"`?

(Other than the obvious thing of parsing the XML myself.)

Answer (score 0):

I've read the source code. See [`QSvgHandler::createSvgNode()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtsvg/src/svg/qsvghandler.cpp.html#3213). The behaviour is something like this:

`QSvgRenderer::viewBoxF()` returns the `viewBox` attribute in user-defined units.

`QSvgRenderer::defaultSize()` reads the `width` and `height` attributes (if present). If the units are `cm`, `in` or `mm` they it is multiplied by an appropriate value to give pixels at a resolution of 90 DPI. For example if `in` then it is multiplied by 90, `mm` by 90/25.4 and so on. Other units - `px`, `pt` and even `%` are left as-is. `defaultSize()` uses integers so its resolution is 1/90 inch.

If the `width` and `height` are *not* present then `defaultSize()` returns the size of the viewBox in user-defined units.

This is rather ad-hoc and complex behaviour and doesn't fit my use case so I think I will just have to parse the XML twice (or the first bit of it anyway).